# Save sklearn pipeline diagram

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, savefig

I want to save a pipeline displayed with the `set_config(display="diagram")` command, see below:

[image: diagram]

Is there a better way to do it than by taking a screenshot?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#visualizing-composite-estimators) may help...

Comment: Thanks @amiola, I tried but it gives me the equivalent of what is shown in my Jupyter Notebook, but on a web page. Printing the content of that web page formats it with page number, url and other things that usually come in the frame of printing a web page. Unfortunately I cannot use that in a report.

Answer (score 4):

```py
from sklearn.utils import estimator_html_repr

with open("pipeline.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(estimator_html_repr(pipeline))
```

Comment: This does not answer the question since the OP clearly asks how to create an image without having to take a screenshot. I might add: could it even be saved as a vector graphic?